# Retrieve Mobile SMS from mobile to PC in VB.NET

Tags: .net, vb.net

How to retrieve Mobile SMS from mobile and save them as excel file or CSV file to PC? using VB.NET

Comment: Your question is **so** broad. You need to try something first, then come to us when you get stuck. Imagine if I asked *How do I transfer a package from America to England*. Firstly, I've not said how big the box is or how heavy it is - you could maybe post it if it were big, or it might be a couple of hundred tonnes of flour which would probably need to be shipped. Secondly I've not said what I've tried - maybe I can't ship it because it contains medical supplies which need to go ASAP, in which case flying might be the only option. You get the idea.

Comment: Your edit doesn't make it any less broad. Stack Overflow is not a coding service nor will we "point you in the right direction". Here we expect **specific** questions regarding **specific** problems or things you wonder about. Do your own research and your own attempts, then come back when you bump into an actual problem. If you want someone to write code for you you're going to have to hire a programmer.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Bit more details would be helpful. Which mobile? Why VB.net?

Usually the manufacturer has provided a 'pc suite' or similar kind of application for making backups device content e.g. https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=51237  or http://www.lg.com/uk/search.lg?search=pc+suite . If you need to develop that kind of app yourself, then looking into platform's SDKs could help. Or any existing apps, as there's something bit similar developed in Java for android at [Github](https://github.com/jberkel/sms-backup-plus).